# Android EditText wraps three dots

Tags: android, android-edittext, word-wrap

How to prevent EditText to wrap three dots at the end of string. How it make to wraps three dots with last word together?

[image]

PS: three dots I add self! It is hint message, which ends with three dots

There is no code, EditText declared in xml. The xml layout is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Добавьте комментарий к фото..."
    android:lines="3"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_input"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:ellipsize="end"` will add dots to the text end if it has greater length than `TextView` or `EditText` capacity if you want it in single line and last world to be end with dots use `andorid:singleline="true"` or if more than one line use it with `android:maxLines="2"` or more.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:singleLine="true"` for your `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:ellipsize="none"` in EditText in your xml file.